# Display two column values in Razor drop down list? or Html drop down list?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Name and ID are stored in database. I want to display all name and ID from database to ViewPage Dropdown. Here I displayed Name column only in drop down. Is there possible to display two columns in single dropdown?? Please let me know the solution.

Controller:

```
var Employe = (from table in dc.tbl_EmployeeDetails
               select table.Employee_Name).ToList();
ViewData["empName"] = Employe ;

var department = (from table in dc.tbl_EmployeeDetails
                  select table.Department).ToList();
ViewData["dept"] = department;
```

View

```
<select id="reportto" disabled="disabled" font-size:14px">
    @foreach(var person in ViewData["empName"] as List<string>)
    {
        if(@Model.employee!=@person)
        {
           <option>@person</option>
        }
    }
</select>
```

Here I have displayed Name only in dropdown. How to display both name and department in single dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the controller:

```html
ViewBag.EmployeeDetails= db.EmployeeDetails.ToList();
```

in the view :

```html
@model ...
@{
        ViewBag.Title ="Employe ";
        List<Proyect.Models.EmployeeDetails> Details = ViewBag.EmployeeDetails;
}

<select name="EmployeeDetails" class="form-control" id="EmployeeDetails">
            <option>Select one</option>
            @foreach (var Detail  in Details)
            {
            <option id="@Docs.Id_Employee_Detail" value="@Docs.Id_Employee_Detail">@Detail.Name : @Detail.Department</option>
            }
</select>
```

and you receive the parameter in the controller

```html
public ActionResult Something(int EmployeeDetails)
{
var EmployeeDetailSelected = dc.tbl_EmployeeDetails.Find(EmployeeDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do one thing .

Please use SelectListItem for bind dropdown list .

```
List<SelectListItem> lstLocation = new List<SelectListItem>();

SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter("@ID", ID),new 
SqlParameter("@Name",Name)};

DataSet dsLocation = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetPersonalInfo", parameters);

   if (dsLocation != null && dsLocation.Tables.Count > 0 && dsLocation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lstLocation = (from drLocation in dsLocation.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                               select new SelectListItem { Text = `drLocation["PersonID"].ToString() + ' - '+ drLocation["PersonName"].ToString(), Value = drLocation["PersonID"].ToString() }).ToList();`
            }
```

and stored this list obejct to view bag and set to Dropdownlist in view .

```
ViewBag.Location=lstLocation ;

@Html.DropDownList("Location", ViewBag.Location as List<SelectListItem>,
 "-SELECT-", new { data_val = "true", data_val_required = "Please select 
 location", @class = "form-control" })
```

using above code , your Data will be like '1-ROnak','2-Manish' in dropdown list .
After selection , you can split using '-' for split name and ID .

Thanks .